# URLs like on a visualstudio.com - advanced routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-routing

I'm writing here becouse one question doesn't let me sleep calmly. How it's possible that site www.visualstudio.com when I sign in to free TFS account, create special 'part' of site with url {myprojectname}.visualstudio.com?. Is it achieveable in my project using ASP.NET MVC 4 or 5? How it doesn't affect in current DNS system? or it affect? What should I read to let my site be so deeply customizable?

for example:

```
user1.mysite.xx
user2.mysite.xx/aaa/4/sda/something_other
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a wildcard DNS A or CNAME entry like (BIND syntax):
*.myside.xx. IN A x.x.x.x

In Windows you can use the command line dns tool for it: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;840687

After that regardless what you write as username.myside.xx it will hit your webserver. From your code you can decide what to do, make a redirect to username.myside.com/username or whatever else